# Requiring a file from a dependency

Tags: javascript, webpack

I have an application (myapp) that uses a lib (mylib) I'm developing. Both use `webpack`.

```
myapp
-->index.js
-->data/info.json
-->node-modules
---->mylib
```

I can easily read the `data/info.json` in the `myapp/index.js` using a simple `require` :

```
const info = require('./data/info.json')
```

Is it possible to read that file from my dependency (mylib) ?
I tried :

```
const info = require(module.parent + './data/info.json')
```

but it didn't work

Comment: Would it be possible to pass it into your module instead of having the module looking for it? e.g. `import mylib from 'mylib'; myLib.doStuff(info);`

Comment: it's probably not a good idea for library to pull anything from application codebase. it should pass data into it, instead of have it pull it.

Comment: No because I want to avoid having try/catches in the parent module. I want to "hide" the complexity of loading the file in "mylib" and keep the parent clean :) Plus I'm curious to find a way to require from a dependency :)